# Hibernate loads list collection twice

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

I have 3 tables in my database, `container`, `item` and `item_container` which is a join_table of many to one between container and item. Entities in code are mapped using 2 classes: `Container` and `Item`.
The relation is unidrectional from `Container` to `Item`.
join_table in hibernate is mapped only by annotations in `Container` class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="container")
public class Container {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "container_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "item_container",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "container_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"))
    private Set<Item> items;

    //getter/setters
}
```

My problem is: when i have the type of collection `Set<Item> items` changed to `List<Item>`, the list contain every Item entity twice. I cant find the reason why, the hashCode and equals methods of Item are based only on the item_id field.

**UPDATE:**

Code for Item class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_template_id", nullable = false)
    private ItemTemplate itemTemplate;

    @Column(name = "item_group")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ItemGroup itemGroup;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private int amount;

    //getter/setters
}
```

Comment: List by default can contains double element ,hashCode and equals methods it will not work with a List they work with a HashSet so if you have  a double element in your table think to use a set

Comment: Well thats the problem. I do not have double elements in the table. I had only 4 elements in item table, so also 4 elements in item_container table. When i pull that data and print list it shows 8 elements. I "fixed" this problem by making the collection a Set, but I am just curious by the unexpected behavior when using List.

Comment: Please post your code for the Item class.